# TypeOrm migration - Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm trying npm run typeorm migration:run in my project and it is showing the error below.

Error during migration run:
Error: Cannot find module 'src/permission/permission.entity'

[image: Error during migratino run: Cannot find module 'permission']

ormconfig.js

```js
module.exports = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 33066,
  username: 'root',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'admin',
  synchronize: false,
  entities: ['./src/**/*.entity.ts'],
  migrations: ['./src/migrations/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: './ts/',
    migrationsDir: './src/migrations',
  },
};
```

What am I doing wrong?
This is my git repo: https://github.com/wesoz/udemy-nest-admin/tree/td/seed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use a relative import path.

```
import { Permission } from '../permission/permission.entity';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I'm getting the error: RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "permissions" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Comment: No idea sorry, maybe you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 9):

Using *typeorm@^0.3.10*

This worked for me.
`npm i -D tsconfig-paths`

Adding this flag to the **ts-node** command `-r tsconfig-paths/register`

```
"migration:run": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run -d=ormconfig.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add decorator @entity()
to entity class

Comment: That's entirely unrelated